# Infinity Scroll and UITableView Data Reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm implementing infinity scroll to load new data in my uitableview that is implemented like Contacts style in Apple embedded App.

My datasource is a IList and then i add new elements on it.
When load new datas to that list if i don't call

```
this.TableView.ReloadData()
```

my UITableView doesn't show the new elements added.

That method generates a ugly effect of white screen for a bit, to show next, succesfully, the data added. There are others ways to do that without that effect?

For example using ReloadRows...i can't use that method because i don't understand in which way pass an NSIndexPath[] for rows that aren't loaded yet

Comment: Can you share some links or code snippets of implementing scroll to load more functionality in xamarin.iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the insertrowsatindexpath methods - see the apple documentation at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html - especially the batch operation section

Comment: It accepts an NSArray. I must cast to my element's list? Data refresh it's auto?

Comment: there will be a MonoTouch version

Comment: this.TableView.InsertRows accepts NSIndexPath[] and UITableViewRowAnimation as parameters (in monotouch). Now i have my List<Object> to add, i must cast to NSIndexPath[] (not reasonable..)?

Comment: Sorry Stuart i've read well documentation and i've understatement how do it using insertrows. That array contains reference to index of rows inserted to comunicate at table view which one have been inserted. Tnx amico